# Access Azure blob storage from AKS

Tags: .net, azure, kubernetes, blob

I have a .Net Core Api that returns data from SQL and a respective pdf/document from Azure Blob container/storage. I am developing a Proof of Concept to host this Api in AKS (Azure Kubernetes). My prototype returns data successfully from SQL (on Linux). However, I am unable to pull the document/pdf from blob storage.

Need information on how I can access blob storage from AKS.

Many thanks Ramesh

Comment: Can you, please, share the code which you are tried ? How you what authenticate to Blob Storage, with Key, temporary SAS, Azure AD account or you have public storage? How Storage Firewall is configured?

Comment: assuming you can reach outside resources (which sounds like it if SQL queries work), then this is not an AKS issue but something with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blobfuse to access Blob storage from AKS.

Blobfuse works by creating a virtual file system on a Linux host. Whenever a file on that system is requested, the driver will retrieve it from Blob Storage and put it in a temporary folder so the operations can be completed, then it writes the changed file back to Blob Storage once the file handles on the file have been released.

**Tradeoff**: Access to files may be slow and highly latent.

**Advantage**: Cheaper than file storage for the same relative amount of data.

Links: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/install-driver-on-aks.md

https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/examples/triton_gpt2_example_azure_setup.html

Comment: Please help me to understand where we can get volumeHandle value in the PersistentVolume configuration?